# TypeScript conversión String a Hex errónea

Tags: angular, typescript, conversión-de-tipos, angular-cli

Estoy intentando convertir un String a Hex en TypeScript (Angular Cli 9).

```
 let cadena:bigint = BigInt("36109611575303940");
 let hexa:string = cadena.toString(16);
 console.log("valor: " + hexa);
```

Estoy utilizando:

- Angular Cli 9
- TypeSript 3.8.3
- Node 12.16.1
- IDE VCode 1.44.0

y me aparece el siguiente error al compilar la aplicación:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:64:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigInt'.
> let cadena:bigint = BigInt("36109611575303940");
>
> src/app/app.component.ts:65:43 - error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
> let hexa:string = cadena.toString(16);

la configuración de mi archivo *tsconfig.app.json* es el siguiente:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

He probado a eliminar *"types":[]* como se apunta en otras soluciones que encontré pero no funciona. También intenté no utilizar *BigInt()* y cambiarlo por un *parseInt()* pero es un número demasiado grande para guardar en un int y al realizar la conversión a hex es errónea (devuelve 8049801aec5f00 en lugar de 8049801aec5f04)
¿Se os ocurre alguna solución al error de BigInt o alguna forma de poder pasar un número tan grande a hex?

Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solucionar el problema con la función que aparece aquí:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626844/convert-a-large-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-javascript

Sin necesidad de utilizar BigInt y realizando la conversión correctamente =). Simplemente modificando la primera linea quedando:

*let dec = str.split(''), sum = [], hex = [], i, s*

en lugar de

*var dec = str.toString().split(''), sum = [], hex = [], i, s*

Answer (score 0):

Si no puedes usar `BigInt`, utiliza esta función:

```
public numHex(s){
let a = s.toString(16);
if ((a.length % 2) > 0) {
    a = "0" + a;
}
return a;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero creo que hay algún problema con la conversión. Por ejempo, para el valor 36109611575303940 su valor hex es 8049801AEC5F04 pero el *.toString(16) devuelve 8049801AEC5F00, lo mismo pasa si se quiere pasar a oct. El valor correcto es 2002230003273057404 pero *.toString(8) devuelve 2002230003273057400. Muchas gracias!